# Where do I put picture in my ASP.Net MVC2 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, image

Where do I place images within my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create `Images` folder inside `Content` folder. Most 3rd party components that use .css files search `images` subdirectory for their images by default.

Answer (score 2):

You could put them in the `Content` folder, along with your .css files. Or you could create a brand new folder and organize it any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

In the content folder.

Answer (score 0):

We have a separate resources domain that serves up all static content (recommended). In the solution, I just have  a 'resources' folder that mimics the structure of the production folder. Easier to deploy using a script. You can create a separate site or vdir on your local web server and map it to this static folder. The location could then be refernced in your project via an app setting (configuration.resourcedomain + "/resources/images/xyz.jpg")